# sharing file through other app

Tags: android, android-intent, file-sharing

I wanted to share a file through google drive. So when i click a button in my app, it should upload the file through google drive app in my mobile without having the user to select the app. Below is the code of the app that I have did so far.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button sharingButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        sharingButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            shareIt();
            }
            });

    }

    private void shareIt() {
        //sharing implementation here
        Intent i=new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.setType("application/pdf");
        //i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Subject test");
        //i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "extra text that you want to put");
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(getFileStreamPath("/storage/sdcard0/tweek/pdf.png"));
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i,"Share via"));
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

So when i click the button it is showing  me the following error.

```
08-02 13:11:40.988: E/AndroidRuntime(25569): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-02 13:11:40.988: E/AndroidRuntime(25569): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File /storage/sdcard0/tweek/pdf.png contains a path separator
08-02 13:11:40.988: E/AndroidRuntime(25569):    at android.app.ContextImpl.makeFilename(ContextImpl.java:1921)
08-02 13:11:40.988: E/AndroidRuntime(25569):    at android.app.ContextImpl.getFileStreamPath(ContextImpl.java:945)
08-02 13:11:40.988: E/AndroidRuntime(25569):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getFileStreamPath(ContextWrapper.java:182)
08-02 13:11:40.988: E/AndroidRuntime(25569):    at com.example.shareapp.MainActivity.shareIt(MainActivity.java:38)
08-02 13:11:40.988: E/AndroidRuntime(25569):    at com.example.shareapp.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:32)
```

Could someone please explain me. I have went through a lot of docs but I am getting confused.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

change this

`Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(getFileStreamPath("/storage/sdcard0/tweek/pdf.png"));`

to

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(getFileStreamPath("file:///mnt/storage/sdcard0/tweek/pdf.png"));
```

or

```
Uri.parse(new File("/mnt/storage/sdcard0/tweek/pdf.png"))
```

it should solve your crash/error

Comment: ok, it is showing me the sharing options and when i select google drive, it is displaying a toast as "uploading one file" but in the drive there is nothing.

Comment: then check your drive setting. why you are using sdcard0 but not sdcard?

Comment: That is the sdcard in my mobile. The external sd card is extSdcard.And when i tried to send it through email or gmail, it is showing me that the file does not exist. but the file is there.

Comment: Uri.parse(new File(/mnt/storage/sdcard0/tweek/pdf.png")) solved my problem. Thank you.

Comment: @Michal YW, Happy Coding.